# Does XMPP supports OAuth as Authentication mechanism in protocol spec?

Tags: oauth-2.0, xmpp

I am making an Application that uses XMPP as its communication protocol, but for better user experience for my application I want the end user to be able to register and login via facebook/google or any OAuth2 provider (eg. github).

Does the XMPP protocol itself support user authentication via OAuth like POP3 or IMAP does. I mean what's the appropriate message format for OAuth2 authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XMPP protocol itself supports SASL authentication, also later Specs of SASL support OAuth2 and OAuth1.a as seen in [rfc7228](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7628).

Also XMPP supports other bindings except TCP such as Websocket one ([RFC7395](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7395)) or the slower BOSH. In this case you can use the "traditional" apis for OAuth2, in other words do OAuth2 as would be done on a classic Web-based application ans use the XMPP as message/data transfer.

So the answer to your questions is YES it supports OAuth2 as spec says so.

Comment: Though upon implementation it may differ.